# Pentaho BI Dashboard use x-action asynchronously

Tags: asynchronous, pentaho, dashboard, xaction

I have this problem. I want to use xaction on a dashboard in response to button click. I don't care about result of this xaction. Just want it to run. Problem is - it runs for about half an hour, and blocks browser until it completes. What I want to do is run x-action without blocking browser.

I tried to use x-action component in CDE, and tried to execute $.ajax directly. I even tried to pass parameter async: true, which should be default, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It's my fault again.
I was thinking one thing, and writing something else. What I did was add async: false instead of async: true.

Changed that thing, and now it's working. Nevertheless according do jquery documentation it should be true by default. Anyway if someone is looking for this kind solution - don't user componet. Ask X-action directly through ajax, and make sure it's set to be asynchronous.